# Why aren’t agents of some verbs the same with agents of to-infinitive or gerund when they are objects?

Tags: clauses

> I asked to see my accountant.
>
> He said to meet him here.
>
> I can smell burning.
>
> I said to go.

Why aren’t agents of some verbs the same with agents of to-infinitive or gerund when they are objects?

Normally, if I omit an subject of a non-finite clause (an object of a main clause) and to-infinitive or gerund becomes an object, an agent of a verb of the non-finite clause and that of a main clause are the same.

> Different: I want to go. vs. I want someone to go.
>
> Different: I need to go. vs. I need someone to go.

But four examples above differ.

> Same: I can smell burning. vs. I can smell something burning.
>
> Same: I asked to see my accountant. vs. I asked someone to see my accountant.

Comment: In principle, ***I like burning*** could mean *I like **to get sunburnt*** as well as ***I like me [or other people] burning things***. But the general principle is that verb subjects (or indeed, ***any*** elements within an utterance) can often be omitted if the intended meaning is obvious without being thus explicitly stated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then if well understood can I omit “door” here? I want the door to be open vs I want to be open.

Comment: I said predictable elements can ***often*** be omitted, not ***always***. But offhand I'm not sure there would be ***any*** contexts where you can discard the object in *[Subject] wants [Object] to be [Verbed/Adjective]* EXCEPT where the Subject and Object refer to the same entity (i.e. - the construction is "reflexive", as in *I want [**me**] to be rich*).

Comment: (i.e. - *I want to be open* can only mean *I would like **myself** to be open / honest / forthcoming*.)

Comment: Okay - on reflection, you could say ***I want well done*** in a restaurant when the waiter asks ***How would you like your steak**?* Note that we normally include the object even there *(I want **mine** [to be] well done)*. But in principle that waiter might have asked ***Would you like the window open or closed**?*, in which case you could feasibly reply ***I want open*** to mean *I want **the window** [to be] open*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you.